# Is there a way in angular (unit testing) to find a component by its @Input() property values?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

This question refers to angular unit tests. I'm searching for a short way to find components by the values, which they receive through their `@Input()` data binding.

I have the following child component `MyComponent`. Which has an `@Input() property called`id`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component,
    template: `... something ...`
})
class MyComponent {
    @Input() id: string;
}
```

I use this component inside a `ParentComponent` and pass different `ids` through the `@Input()` property:

```
...
<my-component [id]="first-comp"></my-component>
<my-component [id]="second-comp"></my-component>
...
```

Now I have a unit test for the `ParentComponent`. If I want to find the two components by their `id` I'm doing this:

```
let firstComponent: MyComponent;
let secondComponent: MyComponent;

const myComponents = debugElement.query(By.css('my-component'));
for (const myComponent of myComponents) {
    if (myComponent.componentInstance.id === 'first-comp') {
        firstComponent = myComponent.componentInstance;
    } else if (myComponent.componentInstance.id === 'second-comp') {
        secondComponent = myComponent.componentInstance;
    }
}
```

This code is not very easy to write. Does angular provide a function like, to do this in an easier way without the for-loop? Something like this:

```
const firstComponent = debugElement.query(By.css('my-component[id="first-component"]'));
const secondComponent = debugElement.query(By.css('my-component[id="second-component"]'));
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case you can simply assign them with this

```
const [firstComponent, secondComponent] = debugElement.query(By.css('my-component'));
```

Which is way easier to write.

You can also CSS selectors :

```
    const firstComponent = debugElement.query(By.css('my-component:first-of-type'));
    const secondComponent = debugElement.query(By.css('my-component:last-of-type'));
```

Comment: Thank you. I know about these possibilities with css-selectors (`nth-of-child` and others), but then my tests are also dependent on the order in my view. If I swap these to components, I need to adjust my tests. Thats why I want to access the components through their `id`.

Comment: Not sure you can. But since your IDs are string, try setting the `[attr.id]` with the same value, so that you can query it through the css selector

Comment: I did it like that in the first time. But then there is an overhead of code in the source code of the component, which is not used by the app, it's only there for the tests. Think that is not a good way either...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I did found a pretty nice way. You can pass a custom function into the `query` function of the `debugElement`.

So I wrote a custom "check" function:

```
export function findByComponentId(id: string): (queryDebugElement: DebugElement) => boolean {
    return (queryDebugElement: DebugElement) => {
        if (queryDebugElement.componentInstance) {
            if (queryDebugElement.componentInstance.id === id) {
                return queryDebugElement.componentInstance;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
}
```

And then I can easily use it like this:

```
const firstComponent = debugElement.query(findByComponentId('first-component'));
const secondComponent = debugElement.query(findByComponentId('second-component'));
```

To use it with different `@Input()` properties or in a more general way, you could create a more general function. So the writer of the test can define for which the component should be checked:

```
export function findIfMatches(check: (component: any) => boolean): (queryDebugElement: DebugElement) => boolean {
    return (queryDebugElement: DebugElement) => {
        if (queryDebugElement.componentInstance) {
            if (queryDebugElement.componentInstance.id === id) {
                return check(queryDebugElement.componentInstance);
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
}

const firstComponent = debugElement.query(findIfMatches(component => component.id === 'first-component'));
const secondComponent = debugElement.query(findIfMatches(component => component.id === 'second-component'));
```